# How to create singleton Page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

We can use a class implement IHttpHandlerFactory to override or intercept the create progress of Page's instance 
In a word we can use:
            PageHandlerFactory factory = (PageHandlerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PageHandlerFactory), true);
            IHttpHandler handler = factory.GetHandler(context, requestType, url, pathTranslated);
            return handler;
to create new instance of asp.net page object.
But you know, the page is not in persistence
If you save the object in applicationstate or session, when next request, you can get the page,but you will find the Application(HttpApplication) in "Page.Context" is null.
In that, the page visit will fail and it cannot be a singleton one.
How to set the httpApplication?

Comment: The title of your question conflicts with the contents. In the title, you say you have a singleton page, but in the question, you say "create new instance of asp.net page object" and then it is not a singleton (which would not work anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all of your question, but I guess you are looking for `HttpContext.Current.Application`

Use that instead of `Page.Context.Application`.

Comment: I save the page instance in ApplicationState when the first request.
Then on second request,I get it from applicationState.
If a use the instance, an error will be found,which is about null pointer on The HTTPApplication on the context of it.
I cannot set it because the object is protected.How to do?

Comment: Then use httpContext.Current.Application in the page you save, and you'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to call the internal protected FrameworkInitialize() function after the page has been constructed.